# Database Engine Services and Integration Services failed during SQL Server 2022 installation

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2022, setup

[image]

Please, what can i do concerning the issue?

Comment: Welcome to the DBA.SE community. Please consider adding the relevant parts of the log file mentioned in the setup summary. It can provide specific details on the exact root cause. Is this a local (laptop/ desktop) installation or an installation on a server? Do you have appropriate rights to install software on the target computer? What edition are you trying to install? (Enterprise / Standard / Evaluation / Developer). Please add more details to the question by clicking on [edit]. Thanks.